# Implementing Curved Bottom Navbar in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, navbar, navigator

I have been trying to create a bottom navbar with https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html but one of my tab button is above a center curve (No Animation). I found some tutorials for flutter and Android Studio but couldn't find any for react native.[image: Curved Bottom Navbar]
What would be the right approach for this.

Comment: You can add a custom component that has a QR with backgroundColor and top in negative

Comment: How would that bring the curve?

Comment: You can add to circle padding

Comment: Wouldn't solve my problem

Comment: My thoughts are 1) add an empty item in your bottom tab nav to get the space between items in tabs, then if you just want to add a QR in just in Home screen add it in absolute position and handle your measures, 2) add components to your tab navigator and let him take some styles like a margin and padding

Comment: If you want to try the second option but, you can't handle the curve because the component takes the same background in the bottom tab, try this in your code ```QR: {
      screen: () => null, // Empty screen
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: <QRButton />, // QR button component "with your style (top, padding, bg, border radius etc"
      }),
    }```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LsLgHeX500

Comment: @Ziyo oh that's perfect, i think my thoughts are Bullshit